# Why am I getting a 200 even though the file path uploaded isn't being stored in the db?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

I'm trying to send the `file`, `user_id`, `email` and Bearer `access_token` in my POST request but for some reason - I'm getting a `200` but the aforementioned data isn't being stored in the database.   In Postman, all works fine though.

Here's the response in the `axios.post(..)` `console.log(response)` line. You could see that the `data: {}` is empty.  But why?

```
{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {url: "http://myendpoint/api/auth/wall-of-fame", method: "post", data: FormData, headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), …}
data: {}
headers: {cache-control: "no-cache, private", content-type: "application/json"}
request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object
```

What could be problem?  I have a Laravel and a React.js codebase that are completely separate projects.

Frontend code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Upload extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedFile: null,
            id: null,
            email: ''
        };
        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("Inside componentDidMount()");
        let id = localStorage.getItem("id");
        let email = localStorage.getItem("email");
        this.setState({
            id: id,
            email: email
        })
        console.log(id);
        console.log(email);
    }

    onFormSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.fileUpload(this.state.selectedFile);
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({ selectedFile: e.target.files[0] }, () => this.state.selectedFile);
    }

    fileUpload(file) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("access_token").slice(13,-8);

        console.log(accessToken);
        console.log(this.state.id);
        console.log(this.state.email);
        console.log(file.name);
        formData.append('file',file.name);
        formData.append('user_id', this.state.id);
        formData.append('email', this.state.email);

        const headers = {
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : "*"
        }

        axios.post('http://myendpoint/api/auth/wall-of-fame', formData, {headers})
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form encType='multipart/form-data' id="login-form" className="form" onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                <input type="file" name="file" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                <button type="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>
        );
    }

}

export default Upload;
```

Here's my controller code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class FileUploadController extends Controller {

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $user = Auth::user();

//        dd($user);
        if($user) {
            $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $email = Auth::user()->email;
            $filePath = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
            $data = [
                'file_path' => $filePath,
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'email' => $email
            ];
            DB::table('mydb.photos')->insert($data);
        }

        return response()->json($user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should try inserting into database using a model? I mean `Model::create()`

Comment: I think you should do `.then(response => response.json)` after `axios.post()`

Comment: @RCRalph I'm thinking there's something wrong with how I'm doing the post request in the `axios.post`.

Comment: Maybe you should try doing something similar to this?

Comment: https://github.com/RCRalph/QuickPay/blob/master/resources/js/components/ExchangeClass.js#L134

Comment: That's how I handled a post request, I'm thinking that you should try that solution :)